# SPFx. Error while importing modernizr in SPFx

Tags: sharepoint-online, jquery, spfx, spfx-webparts, typescript

I am new to SPFx and I am getting an error while trying to add jQuery and external JS in SPFX.

Example my web-part name is `FlipBookWebPart` and I am trying to add `turn.js` and `modernizr.js` into the `FlipBookWebPart.ts`.

I have declared the `modernizr` in config.json like:

[image]

And below is an error that I received when add the web-part in local-workbench.

[image]

In the `webpart.ts`, I add `jQuery` and `modernizr` using following code

```
 import * as jQuery from "jquery";
 import "jqueryui";
 require('modernizr');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try following steps:

1. Run `npm i modernizr` and then `npm i @types/modernizr --save-dev`.
2. Then add its reference to `config.json` in `externals{}` like:

```
    "externals": {
        "modernizr": {
          "path": "node_modules/modernizr/src/modernizr.js",
          "globalName": "modernizr"
        }
     }
```

3. Then reference the file in your `WebPart.ts` file like:

```
    import * as modernizr from 'modernizr';
```

**Reference**:

[Use existing JavaScript libraries in SharePoint Framework client-side web parts](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/web-parts/guidance/use-existing-javascript-libraries).

Comment: Thanks.. I will check on that

Answer (score 0):

It seems like modernizr script from the CDN does not contain any modules. Try to use **SPComponentLoader**.

```
import { SPComponentLoader } from '@microsoft/sp-loader';
```

Inside your `render()` or `onInit()` method (**onInit()** is more preferable, because it runs only once):

```
SPComponentLoader.loadScript('https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js', {
    globalExportsName: 'jQuery'
}).then(($: any) => {
    $(function() {
        console.log('jQuery is loaded');
    });
    SPComponentLoader.loadScript('https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/modernizr/2.8.3/modernizr.js', {
        globalExportsName: 'Modernizr'
    }).then((Modernizr: any) => {
        if (Modernizr.touchevents) {
            console.log('touch');
        } else {
            console.log('no touch');
        }
    });
});
```

Or you can just use modernizr without loading jQuery.

Also, some [info](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/web-parts/guidance/use-existing-javascript-libraries#non-module-scripts-considerations) on adding non-module scripts.